# integration question $\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^a\frac{dx}{(x-b)^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to integrate this integral $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\bigg(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\bigg)^a\frac{dx}{(x-b)^2}$ where $0<a<1$ and $b>1$

Answer. I put this into online integral calculator, but it said it cann't do this integration.

Comment: There are a lot of integrals that the online integral calculator can't handle. Try wolfram alpha

Comment: @clathratus, I used wolfram alpha also, it said 'Standard computation time exceeded'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, substitute $t = (1-x)/(1+x)$.

$$\begin{aligned} I = \int_{-1}^{1}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^{a}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x-b)^{2}} &= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{a}\left(\frac{x+1}{x-b}\right)^{2}\mathrm{d}t \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{a}\,\mathrm{d}t}{(1-t-b(1+t))^{2}} \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{a}\,\mathrm{d}t}{((1-b) - (1+b)t)^{2}} \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{a}\,\mathrm{d}t}{((b+1)t + (b-1))^{2}}\end{aligned}$$

Let $b_{\pm} = b\pm 1$. Then after $u = b_{+}t/b_{-}$,

$$\begin{aligned} I = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{a}\,\mathrm{d}t}{(b_{+}t + b_{-})^{2}} &= \frac{2}{b_{-}^{2}}\left(\frac{b_{-}}{b_{+}}\right)^{a+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{a}\,\mathrm{d}u}{(u+1)^{2}}.\end{aligned}$$

Using the beta function

$$ \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{y-1}\,\mathrm{d}z}{(z+1)^{x+y}},$$

we identify $x=1-a$ and $y=1+a$. Then

$$ I = \frac{2}{b_{-}^{2}}\left(\frac{b_{-}}{b_{+}}\right)^{a+1}\frac{\Gamma(1-a)\Gamma(1+a)}{\Gamma(2)}.$$

Using the reflection identity $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \pi/\sin\pi z$ and recursion $\Gamma(1+a) = a\Gamma(a)$, we have

$$ \frac{\Gamma(1-a)\Gamma(1+a)}{\Gamma(2)} = \Gamma(1-a)a\Gamma(a) = \frac{\pi a}{\sin\pi a}.$$

The answer is then

$$ I = \frac{2}{(b-1)^{2}}\left(\frac{b-1}{b+1}\right)^{a}\frac{b-1}{b+1}\frac{\pi a}{\sin\pi a} = \boxed{\frac{2}{b^{2}-1}\left(\frac{b-1}{b+1}\right)^{a}\frac{\pi a}{\sin\pi a}.}$$

Comment: why did you multiply the right hand side integral by $\frac{1}{b^2-1}$?

Comment: That comes from simplifying the $b$ terms: $(b-1)(b+1)$. Notice the exponent on $b_{-}/b_{+}$.

Comment: ,but $du=\frac{b+1}{b-1}dt$ and $u^a=\bigg(\frac{(b+1)t}{b-1}\bigg)^a$. So the term $\bigg(\frac{b-1}{b+1}\bigg)^{a+1}$outside the integral cancels the term Inside the integral.

Comment: So first, you pull $1/b_{-}^{2}$ out of the integral, then you do u-sub. The term $t^{a}$ pulls $(b_{-}/b_{+})^{a}$ out of the integral, while $\mathrm{d}t$ pulls another factor of $b_{-}/b_{+}$. There is no cancellation; $(b_{-}/b_{+})^{a+1}$ is the result of the substitution.